# Why the $\Delta x$ in a Riemann sum of an integral is replaced with dx...

Tags: calculus

Is there a connection between the equation of a differential $df=f'(x) \Delta x$ and replacing $\Delta x$ in $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x) \Delta x$ with $dx$ in the equation $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x) \Delta x = \int f(x) dx$? The derivative part of the differential is not in the Riemann sum.

I'd be fine with an answer that's in terms of when to use $\Delta x$ in the differential and when to use $dx$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've only seen (and I would only use) $dx$ in the "equation of a differential" $df = f'(x) \,dx$.
But to answer your question, the $dx$ in the integral is kind of just notation (at least until you start doing something fancier). It's supposed to represent a very small, or infinitely small $\Delta x$.

I would say there is an unofficial rule of notation: for finite things like a finite Riemann sum, use $\Delta x$. But if you take a limit of some quantity, and under this limit $\Delta x$ goes to 0, then replace $\Delta x$ with $dx$ (as notation).

$\lim \,( \dotsm \Delta x \dotsm ) = (\dotsm dx \dotsm)$